Why does the Camera2 API restrict exposure time on my Moto phone, but the default camera app allows longer exposures?
I’m developing an Android app using the Camera2 API to capture images on two phones, a OnePlus and a Moto, both of which use the same camera sensor. My app uses manual camera controls (ISO, exposure time, etc.) and works fine on the OnePlus. However, on the Moto phone, when I try to set the exposure time greater than 0.2 seconds, the resulting image is completely black.
The same issue does not occur in the default camera app on the Moto phone, where long exposures (e.g., 1 second or more) work as expected. Here's a breakdown of the behavior I'm seeing:
- OnePlus phone:

Exposure range: [102500 ns (~0.1 ms), 56525698802 ns (~56.5 seconds)]
My app works fine and captures long exposures as expected.

- Moto phone:

Exposure range: [55008 ns (~0.055 ms), 201871757 ns (~0.2 seconds)]
When I try to set exposure times greater than 0.2 seconds in my app, the images come out completely black.
However, the default camera app on the Moto can capture images with exposure times longer than 0.2 seconds without any issue.

My Code for Configuring Capture:
Here's a snippet of how I configure the camera capture with manual settings:
private fun configureCommonCaptureSettings() {
    captureRequestBuilder.apply {
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_OFF)
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF)
        set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, imageSize.toByte())
        set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, JPEG_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT)
        set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomRect)
        if (focusMode == FocusMode.MANUAL) {
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, focusDistance)
        }
        addTarget(imageReader.surface)
    }
}

@Synchronized
private fun captureImage(iso: Int, shutter: Double, awb: Int, imageName: String) {
    if (isCameraAsleep) wakeCamera()
    currentImageName = imageName
    configureCommonCaptureSettings()
    captureRequestBuilder.apply {
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, awb)
        set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, iso)
        set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, (shutter * NANOSECONDS_IN_SECOND).toLong())
    }
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageReaderListener, imageCaptureHandler)
    cameraCaptureSession?.capture(captureRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, imageCaptureHandler)
}


What I’ve Tried:

Checking Exposure Range: I logged the exposure time ranges for both phones, and it’s clear that the Moto phone has a much shorter maximum exposure time:


OnePlus: [102500, 56525698802] (up to ~56.5 seconds)
Moto: [55008, 201871757] (up to ~0.2 seconds)
This confirms that the Camera2 API on the Moto limits exposure to 0.2 seconds, but the default camera app can go beyond this.


Using Maximum Exposure Time: I adjusted my app to capture images at the maximum allowed exposure time on the Moto (0.2 seconds), but I would like to capture longer exposures as the default camera app does.

Simulating Longer Exposure: I’m considering capturing multiple frames at the maximum exposure and stacking them to simulate longer exposure, but I’m wondering if there’s a better way.


My Question:

How is the default camera app able to achieve longer exposures on the Moto phone, even though the Camera2 API limits the exposure time to 0.2 seconds?
Are there any proprietary or manufacturer-specific Camera2 extensions that the default app might be using to bypass this limit?
Is there a way I can achieve similar long-exposure results in my Camera2 API implementation without hitting the 0.2-second exposure limit?

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how I can achieve longer exposures in my app, especially if there's a way to tap into Moto-specific optimizations or workarounds.
Thank you!
